# Не работает rsync в fabric/patchwork

Tags: python

Пытаюсь скопировать файлы с локальной машины (Windows 10™) на удаленную (Ubuntu 16.04) с помощью [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)/[patchwork](https://github.com/fabric/patchwork):

```
from fabric import Connection
from patchwork.transfers import rsync

with Connection(REMOTE_IP, user='root', connect_kwargs={'key_filename': KEY_FILE}) as c:
    rsync(c, SRC_DIR, '/root/build/', strict_host_keys=False)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> "rsync" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Хотя путь к ней прописан в PATH. Подозреваю, что rsync запускается с очисткой переменных окружения, в результате чего исполняемый файл не находится.

Как заставить работать rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целях безопасности, по дефолту, раннеры задач в fabric используют опцию конфигурации `replace_env=True` и пустой словарь `env`, что вызывает запуск `rsync` без переменной `PATH` в окружении. Достаточно поменять это свойство в контексте:

```
c.config.run['replace_env'] = False
```

чтобы все заработало.